# Add product dimension while they are empty - Add/edit product - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

Shipping rates are calculated using product weight and dimension on my Woocommerce website. However, my inventory system only uses product weight for shipping rates. Because of this, new products synchronized from the inventory system to the website generally don't have dimensions.

After a few tests, I found that adding a length, width and height of .001 to products on the site generates the most accurate shipping rates.

I need to write a function that sets product dimensions to .001 if they're empty at the point of creation.

Here is what I've attempted:

```
function add_default_dimension_if_empty( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( $meta_key == '_edit_lock' ) {
        if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' ) {
            //get product
            $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
            $newDim = .001;
            if($product->has_dimensions()){
                if(empty( $product->get_length() )){
                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_length', $newDim);
                }
                if(empty( $product->get_width() )){
                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_width', $newDim);
                }
                if(empty( $product->get_height() )){
                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_height', $newDim);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'add_default_dimension_if_empty', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'add_default_dimension_if_empty', 10, 4 );
```

I used the structure from [this](https://www.mootpoint.org/blog/woocommerce-hook-product-updated-added/) article, but it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine just need to change one condition which check the dimension is exist or not. 
Replace `if($product->has_dimensions())` line with following

```
    $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();
    if(! empty( $dimensions ))
```

This will work for you.